# Erro de Sintaxe ao converter em JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou tentando enviar alguns parâmetros via ajax para um código PHP para realizar uma pesquisa em banco de dados, porém estou com problema na conversão para objeto JSON.
Ele dá SyntaxError:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Mesmo que eu consiga converter para JSON fora do ajax. Se eu tiro o dataType: 'json' do ajax ele envia, porém o SyntaxError ocorre no PHP e só consigo visualizar a string, mas se tento utilizar em um if por exemplo ela é NULL. Outra coisa que reparei é que quando ela envia para PHP o tamanho da string é maior do que ela realmente é. Já vasculhei várias perguntas semelhantes, eliminei caracteres invisíveis, replace, BOM, e nada funciona.
Meu código:

```
filtro_setor=$("#setor").val();
filtro_dpt=$("#departamento").val();
filtro_amb=$("#ambiente").val();

info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"filtro1": filtro_setor,"filtro2": filtro_dpt,"filtro3":filtro_amb}));

$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "consulta_php.php",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: info,
            success: function(dados, response) {
                    alert('Deu Boa');
                    console.log(dados);

                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    alert("Deu ruim");
                    console.log(error);
                }
        })
        ;

//E O PHP
var_dump($_POST);
$filtro1 = json_decode($_POST["filtro1"]); //SETOR
$filtro2 = json_decode($_POST["filtro2"]); //DEPARTAMENTO
$filtro3 = json_decode($_POST["filtro3"]); //AMBIENTE
```

Answer (score -4):

É que tais tentando pegar suas informações do JSON dentro do $_POST.
todo seu JSON esta tendo de um nó do $_POST e vc tem que descobrir qual é.
Tenta desta forma se funciona.

```
$payload = json_decode($_POST);
$filtro1 = $payload["filtro1"];
$filtro2 = $payload["filtro2"];
$filtro3 = $payload["filtro3"];
```

Comment: Olá, primeiramente obrigado por tentar resolver. 
O problema é que o json_decode trata uma string por vez e não um array inteiro.
Pelo que estou percebendo é algum problema com a codificação, porque eu consigo visualizar o json como array, porém se eu tento manipular como STRING ela retorna NULL.
Inclusive o json_last_error_msg retorna Syntax Error.